# T tests in R- unable to run together

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, t-test

I have an airline [dataset](http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/the-data.html) from stat computing which I am trying to analyse.

There are variables DepTime and ArrDelay (Departure Time and Arrival Delay). I am trying to analyse how Arrival Delay is varying with certain chunks of departure time. My objective is to find which time chunks should a person avoid while booking their tickets to avoid arrival delay

My understanding-If a one tailed t test between arrival delays for dep time >1800 and arrival delays for dep time >1900 show a high significance, it means that one should avoid flights between 1800 and 1900. ( Please correct me if I am wrong). I want to run such tests for all departure hours.

**Totally new to programming and Data Science. Any help would be much appreciated.

Data looks like this. The highlighted columns are the ones I am analysing

[image]

Comment: So do you want to test all departure hours against each other? It may be better to test each hour vs. all hours that way you know which times are better/worse than "an average day." Why don't you post some data and what you want the output to look like so we can better help you.

Comment: See this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a R reproducible example

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment. 

So considering just the two columns DepTime and ArrDelay data looks like this [1829(time): 23(delay in minutes)], [1700:10], [1000: 5],[1750:137]. Your idea sounds fine too. I basically want to see which hours  in a day are not so favorable to travel w.r.t delays.

Comment: Please put all code and data necessary to reproduce this in the question itself

Comment: Added a snapshot of the dataset to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing an image of the data is not the same as providing the data for us to work with...

That said I went and grabbed one year of data and worked this up.

```
flights <- read.csv("~/Downloads/1995.csv", header=T)

flights <- flights[, c("DepTime", "ArrDelay")]
flights$Dep <- round(flights$DepTime-30, digits = -2)
head(flights, n=25)

# This tests each hour of departures against the entire day. 
# Alternative is set to "less" because we want to know if a given hour
# has less delay than the day as a whole.

pVsDay <- tapply(flights$ArrDelay, flights$Dep, 
                 function(x) t.test(x, flights$ArrDelay, alternative = "less"))

# This tests each hour of departures against every other hour of the day. 
# Alternative is set to "less" because we want to know if a given hour
# has less delay than the other hours.
pAllvsAll <- tapply(flights$ArrDelay, flights$Dep, 
                           function(x) tapply(flights$ArrDelay, flights$Dep, function (z) 
                             t.test(x, z, alternative = "less")))
```

I'll let you figure out multiple hypothesis testing and the like.

[image]

### All vs All

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am new to stackoverflow. Apologies for not posting the dataset! I understood your code.. however when I run this I am getting the following output..Am I missing something?

 Length Class Mode
0    9      htest list
100  9      htest list
200  9      htest list
500  9      htest list
600  9      htest list
700  9      htest list
800  9      htest list
900  9      htest list
1000 9      htest list
1100 9      htest list
1200 9      htest list
1300 9      htest list
1400 9      htest list
1500 9      htest list

Comment: to access the comparison of hour 900 to the entire day use `pVsDay[[10]]`, to access the comparision between 2200 and 1300 use `pAllvsAll[[23]][[14]]`

Comment: Thanks a lott! Owe you one big time. With advice like this one doesn't get intimidated by programming.

Comment: so I should be able to access just the pvalues by pVsDay[[10]]$p.value right?
Last question..I am struggling to plot the graph. How did you plot it? can a function be used inside qplot or ggplot?

Comment: Correct, ...$p.value will return just the pvalue. It would probably be easiest to extract the pvalues to a new object and then plot

Comment: For storing the pvalues into an object, I am writing this. However, I am getting an error "Error in pVsDay[[i]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index <real>" Can you help me understand where I am going wrong? 

dayplist <- NULL

for (i in seq(0,24,1))
{
  dayplist <- c(dayplist,pVsDay[[i]]$p.value)
  
}

Comment: Indexing starts at 1 not 0. `seq(1, length(pVsDay),1)`

Comment: Can you help me learn how you plotted the above graphs? (Sorry if I sound too ignorant)
for (i in seq(1,length(pAllvsAll),1))
{
  allplist <- c(allplist,pAllvsAll[[i]]$p.value)
  
}

str(allplist)

This works well with pVsDay. This doesnt work for pAllvsAll.  It gives me NULL.  :(

Comment: pAllvsAll is a list of lists, you need to iterate through the second list to get the p.value. Try `str(pAllvsAll)` to see what I mean